# How to choose the first 20 columns in R from dataset

Tags: r, csv, tensor

I need choose the first 20 columns from big massive
[image: The structure of my data]
Here the code

```
library(reshape2)
mydat=read.csv("C:/Users/synthex/Desktop/sales.csv", sep=";",dec=",")
df.sales.t <- acast(mydat, DAY ~ ART ~ STORE , value.var="SALES", fill=0)
```

But, when i do so, i get strange result, you can see structure of my data on screen and result, when i choose the first 10 columns,it show as follow:-

```
dput()
> g=as.data.frame(df.sales.t[,1,1:7])
> g
            956  958   961  974 980  999  1053
01.nov.15 108.0  0.0   0.0  0.0   0  0.0 216.0
02.nov.15   0.0  0.0  97.0  0.0   0  0.0   0.0
03.nov.15   0.0  0.0  97.0 99.9   0  0.0   0.0
04.nov.15 108.0  0.0  97.0  0.0   0  0.0 108.0
05.nov.15   0.0  0.0   0.0 99.9   0  0.0   0.0
06.nov.15 216.0  0.0  97.0  0.0 106  0.0   0.0
07.nov.15   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0 106  0.0   0.0
08.nov.15   0.0 99.9  97.0  0.0   0  0.0 108.0
09.nov.15   0.0  0.0 194.0  0.0   0  0.0 108.0
10.nov.15   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0 106 99.9   0.0
```

How to select exactly those variables that are on the screenshot from `df.sales.t`?

Comment: `new_dat <- mydat[,1:20]`

Comment: @Adamm , not mydat=) I need to select colums from df.sales.t.  It's reshaped mydat dataset (look at screen)  in the dimension of the tensor, how to select from df.sales.t

Answer (score 2):

use

```
mydat1 = df.sales.t
mydat1$rownames = row.names(mydat1)
rownames(mydat1) = NULL
colnames= colnames(mydat1) 
colnames(mydat1) = as.chracter(mydat1)
data <- mydat1[,1:20]
```

Comment: not mydat=) I need to select colums from df.sales.t. It's reshaped mydat dataset (look at screen) in the dimension of the tensor, how to select from df.sales.t  :)

Comment: may be you can try this now

Comment: i got the error after this strings > 'colnames= colnames(mydat1)
> colnames
NULL 
> colnames(mydat1) = as.chracter(mydat1)
Error: could not find function "as.chracter"
> colnames(mydat1) = as.character(mydat1)
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("108", "0", "0", "108", "0",  : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions'

Comment: I think its because of the spelling error in as.character